# Codebuild suddenly fails in DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase: SINGLE_BUILD_CONTAINER_DEAD

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Starting today our codebuild project, which has been working flawlessly for months and not modified has stopped working.
Failure occurs in DOWNLOAD_SOURCE phase, with this message:

**"SINGLE_BUILD_CONTAINER_DEAD: Build container found dead before completing the build. Build container died because it was out of memory, or the Docker image is not supported."**

The applications code is hosted on CodeCommit.
We did not do any modification to the buildspec file, and the very same build was even still working yesterday.

We are using aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:2.0 images, and did not do any modifications but the failure suddenly happened today. During the previous build the job was using at most 20% of the available memory (15GB). The build environment is still Linux, as expected and as what it should be.
Sadly nothing gets logged because it fails even before processing the first commands of the buildspec so it's very hard to debug.

Anyone has any idea on what could cause this ?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: If you go to CW Logs, there is also nothing there? The logs in CB console are usually behind those in CW.

Comment: No the logs aren't even created in Cloudwatch since the build did not actually start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the reason by creating some test build, so I'm sharing the solution I found below.

### Solution

If you are using multiple sources for your build project, **get sure that Git Clone Depth is set to 1 for all your sources**. 
Git clone depth defaults to "Full", so if you have built your project with CloudFormation get sure to include `GitCloneDepth: 1` in your template SecondarySources list.

### Explanation

Not sure about what has changed internally, but there seems to be some kind of timeout when cloning the repos, even though the error message is unclear about that. 
 As of today (2020-10-20), this error is reproductible if you have multiple repos containing enough commits, by creating an empty test project and including 3 additional sources. The build will fail with the same error message before starting.

Once I was able to reproduce the issue, I've tried fiddling around with clone depth and it finally worked. Again, I'm not sure if this is temporary or will be fixed, but as of yesterday (2020-10-19), this workaround was not necessary.

Comment: My clone depth is one and I also get this error.  Seems like a very generic error.